# NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

i am trying to parse the tags of xml, but i am not retrieving any value in my table view. Instead application get terminated  due to exception. here is my code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Table"]) {
        [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook];
        [aBook release];
        aBook = nil;
    }
    else 
        [aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];//problem is here
        [currentElementValue release];
     currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

where as 'appdelegate' object of delegate class, 'Books' is mutable array in delegate class, 'aBook' is the object of 'Book' class, having property n declared strings for tag in xml.

help me out

here is my xml file:

```
<pre><NewDataSet>
−
<Table>
<id>1</id>
<catname>Birthday</catname>
<iid>1</iid>
<subcatname>card1</subcatname>
−
<url>
http://www.orkutpapa.com/scraps/happy-birthday-card-2-3.jpg
</url>
</Table>
−
<Table>
<id>1</id>
<catname>Birthday</catname>
<iid>2</iid>
<subcatname>card2</subcatname>
−
<url>
http://robertpattinsonwho.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/twilight-birthday-card.jpg
</url>
</Table>
−
<Table>
<id>1</id>
<catname>Birthday</catname>
<iid>3</iid>
<subcatname>card3</subcatname>
−
<url>
http://www.funxite.com/media/2373-birthday-card-to-wife.jpg
</url>
</Table>
−
<Table>

</pre>
```

exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key iid.'
>   2011-04-26 10:41:03.388 XML[631:20b] Stack: (

Comment: @user720235: kindly provide me with the XML you're trying to parse.

Comment: Are the objects actually added to the books array? This code looks good. Try NSLogging the count of objects in the books array ?

Comment: In didStartElement, code looks for `table` but in didEndElement it looks for `Table` (uppercase T).  Perhaps that's part of the problem?

Comment: @ahmadTK i have added some xml file tags. i need only the card names that is "birthday....etc etc"in table view and urls in next table view at didselect row at index

Comment: @tejaswi: yes i need to add only card names in Books array. mtrying but apps get terminated.

Comment: @anna: i have corrected the mistake. but still apps get terminated.

Comment: @oded: thanks for editing!! can u let me know how did u displayed xml tag? i am new to this stack

Comment: Like all code on the site, you need to indent it 4 spaces (or select and use the `{}` on the toolbar or `Ctrl + K` on the keyboard)

Comment: @oded: thanks!! can u suggest me the solution for my exception?

Comment: No. I have no experience with objective c.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it should work I was also facing same issue. It crashes in case there is integer value.

```
[aBook setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentElementValue] forKey:elementName];
```